# Blank HTML page with MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql

Does anyone know why this code will not work=

```php
<html>
<head>
<title>Retrieve data from database </title>
</head>
<body>

<?php
include('connection.php');  

$sqlget = "SELECT navcode FROM nav";
$sqldata = mysqli_query($dbcon, $sqlget) or die ('error gettting request');

echo "<table>";
echo "<tr><th>navcode</th></tr></table>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_arrary($sqldata, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    echo "<tr><td>";
    echo $row['navcode'];
    echo "</td></tr>";}
echo "</table>";        
?>
</body>
</html>
```

My database has data however the query page comes up blank.  Am I missing something?

Comment: `$row['navcode'];` maybe you misspelled the name of the column there?

Comment: Your page is blank because you can't see the fatal error. Always develop with error reporting on!  `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`  This would show up as a fatal error indicating an unknown function `mysqli_fetch_arrary`.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you mispelled `mysqli_fetch_array`...

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sqldata, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
```

instead of

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_arrary($sqldata, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
```